# How to add incremental number to ID when cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, clone

I have a form field that I am duplicating when one clicks on the "Add" button. When an ID is duplicated, I want to add an incremental number to it. My code below is appending a 0 to the end of each new ID instead of counting. So #mark-description becomes mark-description00 instead of #mark-description2. I've looked a couple other similar posts here but am unable to determine what I'm doing wrong. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

NOTE: I'm using ids because a jQuery plugin I'm using requires them.

Javascript:

```
$('#add-character-button').on('click', function () {
var source = $('.mark:last'),
clone = source.clone();
var count = 0;

clone.find('.copyme').val($(this).attr('title')).attr('id', function(i, val) {
return val + count;
    });
     clone.insertAfter('.mark:last');
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input class="checkbox" id="standard" name="mark-type" type="checkbox" value="Standard Character">
  <label class="no-placeholder" for="standard-character"></label>
  <div class="standard-mark-container">
    <div class="mark" id="mark-details">
      <div class="mark-name">
        <label class="placeholder" for="mark-name"><span>text</span></label>
          <input class="copyme" id="mark-name" name="mark-name" placeholder="" title="Enter your mark name" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <label class="placeholder" for="mark-description"><span>text</span
        </label>
        <textarea class="copyme" id="mark-description" name="mark-description" placeholder="" title="Enter a description"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="remove"> <a class="remove-mark-button" href="#" id="remove-character-button"><span>Remove</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 <div class="add-mark"><a class="add-mark-button" href="#" id="add-character-button"><span>+ Add</span></a></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need to change the ID's? Why for a DOM element that you are specifically going to clone would you even want to attach an id to it?  Your biggest problem is actually going to be with the name property of the input fields.  These need to change (or use array access notation like `mark-description[]` or your form won't work properly.  You are using a bit of an anti-pattern that people, when first working with javascript/jQuery in a manner like you are trying to do often fall into.

Comment: Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7m8z5su5/1/) which works as, I think, it is supposed to work.

Comment: Um, all your ids would need to change.

Comment: the issue with your code is in your line `var count= 0` being inside the click event. every time, you're resetting count to 0 and just appending it onto the id.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not even be using id's on the items that you are cloning. And you SHOULD be using array access notation (i.e. `mark-name[]`) in your field names. Without this you are only going to get one of the duplicate fields with the same name posted.

Here is what I would suggest.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input class="checkbox" id="standard" name="mark-type" type="checkbox" value="Standard Character">
  <label class="no-placeholder" for="standard-character"></label>
  <div class="standard-mark-container">
    <div class="mark">
      <div class="mark-name">
        <label class="placeholder"><span>text</span>
          <input class="copyme" name="mark-name[]" placeholder="" title="Enter your mark name" type="text">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <label class="placeholder"><span>text</span>
          <textarea class="copyme" name="mark-description[]" placeholder="" title="Enter a description"></textarea>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="remove"><a class="remove-mark-button" href="#"><span>Remove</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 <div class="add-mark"><a class="add-mark-button" href="#" id="add-character-button"><span>+ Add</span></a></div>  
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('#add-character-button').on('click', function() {
    // make clone
    $template = $('.mark:last');
    var $clone  = $template.clone();
    // set values to default in clone
    $clone.find('.copyme').each(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
    });
    // insert into DOM
    $clone.insertAfter($template);
});

$('.remove').on('click'), function() {
    $(this).closest('.mark').remove();
});
```

This fully eliminates the need to modify id names and simplifies your code.

Comment: This is a good answer, but heres my suggestions for improvements.  Since the for attributes must contain ids, I would wrap the inputs with the label elements and remove the for attributes.  Also, it doesnt make sense to me to copy the title in to the field value when you clone.  Why not just reset to ""?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ I just followed the current behavior intended in the original code example with regards to setting default values. Good thought on labels. I will change that.

Comment: @Mike Brant Thanks for your help with this. I'm using ids because a plugin I'm using (In-Field Labels jQuery Plugin) requires them in order to work properly.

Comment: In looking at the code for that plug-in, it would seem that you could easily change the way you bind the labels to the inputs within the `$.fn.inFieldLabels` function to look for nested input rather than using the `for` attribute in the label.

Comment: @Mike Brant I hadn't thought of that. You mean simply use the nested input name instead of tying the `id` to the `for` value?

Comment: @Ken Exactly. You could simply tie the label to the input nested inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for? i simplified the code so i wouldnt have to type all the ids and fors and stuff. http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/134/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        count++;
        var clone = $('.template').clone('true').removeClass('template');
        clone.find('textarea').attr('id', 'textarea' + count);
        clone.find('textarea').html('Id: ' + clone.find('textarea').attr('id'));
        clone.appendTo('.sections');
    });
});

<a href="#" class="add">Add</a>
<div class="sections">
    <div class="template section">
        <input type="checkbox" /><br/>
        text <input type="text"/><br/>
        textarea <textarea id="textarea">Id: textarea</textarea>        
    </div>
</div>
```

although, i would suggest not using id's, but if you're intent on using them, this should work for your purposes.

Comment: You should place your full code in your answer.  Having a fiddle is nice and all, but could go away over time, leaving this answer incomplete.